# Efficient method for generating lists of large prime numbers

Tags: python, performance, math, primes, largenumber

What I'm trying to figure out is when I run this code for smaller numbers it returns the list just fine, but for larger numbers (I would call this small in the context of what I'm working on.) like 29996299, it will run for a long time, I've waited for 45 minutes with no results and had to end up killing the program. What I was wondering was whether there was a more efficient way to handle numbers whose scale was larger than 4 or 5 digits. I've tested a few permutations of the range function to see if there was a better way to handle the limits of the list I want to produce but nothing seems to have any effect on the amount of time it takes to do the computation. I'm new to python and am not that experienced as a programmer. Thank you for your time.

ran the program again before submitting this post and it took an hour and a half or so.

function of the program is to take the User selected number, use it to generate a lower bound, find all primes between the bound and input and append to list, then generate a secound upper bound and find all primes and then append to list, to create a list that extends forwards and backwards from the initial number. 
the program works like I expect it to but not as quickly as I need it to since the numbers I'm going to be dealing with are going to get large quickly, almost doubling at each phase.

```
initial_num = input("Please enter a number. ") 

lower_1 = int(initial_num) - 1000
upper_1 = int(initial_num)
list_1 = []

for num in range(lower_1,upper_1):
   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2,num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           list_1.append(num)

lower_2 = list_1[-1]
upper_2 = list_1[-1] + 2000
list_2 = []

for num in range(lower_2,upper_2 +1):
   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2,num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           list_2.append(num)

list_3 = list_1 + list_2[1:]

print list_3
```

Comment: If the numbers are too large for you to effectively sieve all numbers from 2 to the upper bound for primality, use the Miller-Rabin test for primality ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test ). The sort of trial division that you are trying to implement is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Even using a brute force approach like this, you can also save a lot of computation by realizing that if you haven't found a prime factor by the time you've tested the square root of the number, you never will.  Also, all prime numbers, except for 2 and 3, are multiples of 6 +/- 1.

Comment: Thank you John, I'm familiar with the Miller-Rabin test, but I don't know how to implement it within python, I'm new to coding and still trying to figure out how to adapt my work to programming. I can do the computations by hand, but so far barely scratched the surface as to the data I need to collect.

Comment: Thank's Mark, any pointers as to a specific method? As an amatuer coder I don't know how much I don't know let alone what I should be searching for, not afraid to do the work, just looking for a little direction. The tutorials I've been following have only gotten me as far as the inefficient method I found, I know that It's not the best approach and the methods dealing with creating classes and dictionaries to store and recall the data I need for my research is something I haven't gotten the grasp of yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a more efficient algorithm to generate the entire list of prime numbers up to N. This is the [Sieve of Erathostenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Please have a look at the linked article, it even includes an example pseudocode. The basic idea of the algorithm is:

1. maintain L, a list of potentially prime numbers (initially all numbers from 2 to N)
2. pick the next prime number (p) as the first element of L (intially 2)
3. remove all numbers that are a multiple of p, up to N, since they cannot be prime
4. repeat from step 2

At the end you are left with a list of prime numbers.

An implementation in Pyhton [from here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Python)

```
def eratosthenes2(n):
    multiples = set()
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        if i not in multiples:
            yield i
            multiples.update(range(i*i, n+1, i))

print(list(eratosthenes2(100)))
```

To reduce memory consumpution you could consider usgin a bitset, storing one bit for each number. That should reduce memory usage by between 32 - 64 times. A bitset implementation is available for python [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray).

Comment: Even if is (IMHO) the right answer for someone trying to find all the primes between two given numbers, you should at least provide the general idea of the algorithm instead of a simple link to the wikipedia page.

Comment: That helps, but it runs into a memory error for very large numbers on my computer. I should have mentioned that part of the reason I made two lists and merged them was to save on memory, I don't need all primes, just the ones in the range -1000 through +2000 of the target number. Do you know of a way I can find a compromise between them?

Comment: Try using bitsets to store the numbers. What is the upper bound on the value of N?

Comment: That would help, I just read a brief overview of it, the only issue is in the question you asked, n + 2000 works for 29996299 because I know what I'm looking for is within that range for that value, but unsure once I get to even larger values.

Comment: the bounds for all digits that I'm looking at are -1600 and 70000000